# Adding multiple values to a dictionary

Tags: python

I want to add multiple values to a dictionary key so they act as the X,Y coordinates
like this

```
places = {"HouseNum1":x,y}
```

is there any way to add those two variables to a key like that?

Answer (score 7):

Use a `tuple` or `list`.

```
places = {"HouseNum1":[x,y]}
```